# CSS3 rotate animation not working on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation, rotation

I'm trying to make this working with all browsers, but I can't reproduce the effect in Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/vq3xuafb/

I tried copying the code like this who have -webkit- and changing to -moz-, but not working.

```
#ball_3 {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9);
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 6px 30px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(1440deg) scale(1);}
}
```

Also I don't know if it works on Opera or IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you are missing the standard prefix for `@keyframes`, `animation` and `transform`.

Also, you could minify your `animation` syntax by using this shorthand.

```
animation: rotate 2s infinite cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9);
```

---

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vq3xuafb/2/)**</kbd>

```css
#hidder {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: grey;
  z-index: 99988;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#spinner.active {
  display: block;
}
#spinner {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 48%;
  z-index: 99989;
}
.spinner_ball {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  left: 24px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
#ball_1,
#ball_2,
#ball_3 {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s infinite cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9);
  animation: rotate 2s infinite cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 6px 30px;
  transform-origin: 6px 30px;
}
#ball_2 {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s infinite cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 0.9);
  animation: rotate 2s infinite cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 0.9);
}
#ball_3 {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s infinite cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9);
  animation: rotate 2s infinite cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9);
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1440deg) scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1440deg) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='hidder'></div>
<div id="spinner"> <span id="ball_1" class="spinner_ball"></span>
  <span id="ball_2" class="spinner_ball"></span>
  <span id="ball_3" class="spinner_ball"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I tried with -moz- before but without result :)